# SignalR connection issue on 5G

Tags: .net, azure, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am having a connection issue with SignalR on only 5G mobile data. I am using ASP.NET Core Web API for the backend and Angular for the front end. I am using Azure SignalR, when I am using Wifi or 4G it works fine but when I switch to 5G data I get the following error in the console.

Error: Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets': Error: WebSocket failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled.

Any helping regarding this will be very usefull.

I tried to increase the timeout but still no luck.

Comment: This has nothing to do with SignalR or programming in general. The problem is caused by the mobile connection - the mobile provider and your device's mobile hardware. You can't fix either from some web server. It doesn't matter whether it's 5G or not, . The key word is `mobile` which means flaky, inconsistent connectivity. If the 5G connection is less reliable than 4G you'll have more problems. If the *mobile provider* uses data shaping, you may have problems

Comment: If you use Azure, why not use [Azure Notifications](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/notification-hubs) ? SignalR uses WebSockets, which expects a direct connection to the server. It can handle reconnections but not lost or delayed notifications. All mobile providers use proxies and one form of data shaping or another based on the customer's subscription, which means they may be blocking persistent connections, VPN protocols etc.